# C - How to prompt user to enter filename

Tags: c, printf

Very new to C programming. I'm writing a program where I want to prompt the user to input the name of the file to be open for reading. On my code shown bellow I want to throw an error if it doesn't open or if the file doesn't exist, but when I run it, my code blows up and I have to close the program (DOS)

```
/*ask user for the name of the file*/
  printf("enter file name: ");
  gets(fname);


//Opens the file from where the text will be read. 
fp=fopen(fname, "r");

//Checks if the file us unable to be opened, then it shows the error message 
if (fp == NULL)
    {
     printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading\n");
    }
```

// you can test this by creating a name.txt file. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: How have you defined `fname`? Oh, and please, please, please don't use `gets` -- ever! Consider `fgets` as one possible alternative.

Comment: You should also be clear about what you mean when you say "when I run it", especially if you're new to C. Do you mean it doesn't compile, it crashes immediately on run, or it crashes after you try to enter a file name and push enter?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you should make sure there's enough room in `fname` to store your file name, otherwise you'll almost certainly cause corruption and "blowing up" :-)

For example, the following snippet:

```
char fname[10];
gets (fname);
```

will be problematic if you enter more information than `fname` can hold. At that point, you're into undefined behaviour territory and *anything* can happen.

But, because `gets` provides no way to limit what the user enters, *you should never use it!*

A proper, protected, method of user input can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

It uses `fgets` since that can limit what the user enters. It also allows for a prompt, provides an error indication if something goes wrong, handles end-of-file correctly, and removes the remainder of any too-large line so that it cannot affect the next input operation.

In fact, I'll copy it here to make this answer self-contained:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

You can call it as follows, specifying the buffer and size, and receiving an error indication on return:

```
// Test program for getLine().

int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NewLearner, there are other problems with `scanf`, particularly if you use the 'unbounded string' format string `%s`. It too is subject to buffer overflow. `scanf` means "scan formatted" and there's not much more _unformatted_ than user input :-) Don't get me wrong, it's fine in most cases, especially for learning C, or classwork, or quick-and-dirty programs, but it's no good for production quality code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're missing, but this program compiles and runs for me using cl.exe on the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char fname[100];
    FILE* fp;
    memset(fname, 0, 100);
    /*ask user for the name of the file*/
    printf("enter file name: ");
    gets(fname);


    //Opens the file from where the text will be read. 
    fp = fopen(fname, "r");

    //Checks if the file us unable to be opened, then it shows the error message 
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading\n");
    }

}
```

Also note that certain compilers (including Microsoft's) require you to put all declarations at the top of the function when called with default options.

Answer (score 0):

well,This is what happened with me, adding an  "else" condition for "if" worked for me.Below mentioned is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int  main() 
{

char fname[100];
FILE* fp;
memset(fname, 0, 100);
/*ask user for the name of the file*/
printf("enter file name: ");
gets(fname);

fp = fopen(fname, "r");

//Checks if the file us unable to be opened, then it shows the error message 
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading\n");
}

else
{
    printf("hello");
}


getch();
}
```

Also make sure that you've added "#include" as your header file.