# Specify file extension

Tags: c, file-io

Right now, what I have is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char fname[100];
    FILE* fp;
    memset(fname, 0, 100);

    /* ask user for the name of the file */
    printf("enter file name: ");
    gets(fname);

    fp = fopen(fname, "w");

    /* Checks if the file us unable to be opened, then it shows the 
       error message */
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading\n");
    else
        printf("hello");
    getch();
}
```

This functions just fine, but is there a way I can force it to save as a .txt or a .data or something? Right now it just saves as the name you put in with no extension. Other than asking the user to just input the name and extension, I can't think of a way to do that. I mean, it still works just fine for reading/writing purposes, I just think an extension would be nice.

Comment: man strcat.....

Comment: 1) `#include<conio.h>` non-standard header 2) `int  main(void)` 3) `memset(fname, 0, 100);` : nonsense 4) `printf("enter file name: ");` wont be flushed, add a '\n' 5) `gets(fname);` dont use gets. 6) `getch();` : non standard function 7) `}` main should return an int; yours does not return anything. 8) What was your question, again?

Comment: @wildplasser I copied that from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25950349/7471023 I wasn't trying to make it perfect, just functional.

Comment: @wildplasser: Starting with C99, falling of the end of `main` is equivalent to `return 0;`.

Comment: You might consider letting users specify whatever file names they want, just as you're doing now. If I want a name ending in `.txt`, I can type `.txt`. If I don't, I don't have to.

Comment: If you add `.txt`, you need to make sure the user didn't type `filename.txt` because `filename.txt.txt` is not nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Credit goes to a friend of mine who showed this to me earlier today.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *Fileptr;
    char filename[50];
    char file[50];
    int c;

    printf("What do you want to name your file?");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    sprintf(file, "%s.txt", filename);

    Fileptr = fopen(file, "w");
    fprintf(Fileptr, "Data goes here");
    fclose(Fileptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Much easier than what I had been doing.

Answer (score 1):

to expand my comment:

```
strcat(fname, ".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) function can be used to append text to a destination buffer, assuming the destination is large enough to store the new text.

`char *strcat(char *destination, const char *source);`

The `source` is the new text that you want to append (in your case the extension), and the `destination` is where the new text will be added. If `destination` is not big enough, then the behavior is undefined.

One could also use the [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/?kw=snprintf) function to append text, which is safer, as it takes a size argument.